# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT not working 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm running async task. After finishing process my onpostexecute method will launch the next activity. The next activity will pop up, if i have not opened any other app(in same app). but if i opened other app, my app is not launching after finishing the task, means activity is not brought to front. it will work fine in above LOLLIPOP. Why it is not working in kitkat?

Answer (score 3):

> `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` is only set by `Android` when it brings an activity to the front itself. Setting it yourself does nothing

Android Documentation said.

This flag is not normally set by application code, but set for you by    the system as described in the `launchMode` documentation for the  `singleTask` mode.

See [**LaunchMode documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode)